# Alternative of ng-repeat in the AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array in which the thousands  products and i have iterate the array with the help of the ng-repeat,it is working properly in browser,but in the mobile devices products are load really slow so how to improve the performance time of the products on mobile devices.

Comment: Use pagination instead of rendering all items at once. For example an infinite scroll implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lazy-load` concept. I mean on `scroll` or on clicking any button, let load some number of rows of data.

For **example**:

In First API call, load 20 rows, then again 20+20 using API call.

There are lots of **modules** available like:

See some live examples [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html)

or you can create your own.

Comment: Sir i am begineer in the AngularJS,i don't have any idea how to call the API in the Scroll bar give me suggestion sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('NoticeCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $http, NoticeService, baseUrl) {

  $scope.items = [];

NoticeService.loadNotice().then(function(items) {
if(items != 0)
{
  $scope.items = items;
} else {
  $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
}       
});

$scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
$scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 5;
$scope.limit = 0;

$scope.loadMore = function(limit) {
var start;
var limit;
var j;

for(var i= limit, j=0; j < $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay; i++,j++)
{
  start = i+ 0;
  limit = $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay;
}

$scope.limit = $scope.limit + $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay;
NoticeService.refreshNotice(start, limit).then(function(items){
  if(items != 0)
  {
    $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items);
  } else {
    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
  }

  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
});
  };

})
```

Factory code

```
.factory('NoticeService', function($http , $stateParams, baseUrl){
  var BASE_URL = baseUrl+"api_method=notice.list&api_version=1.0&app_key=12345&user_id="+$stateParams.userId
  var items = [];

  return {
    loadNotice: function(){
     var start = 0;
    var limit = 4;
  return $http.get(BASE_URL+"&start="+start+"&limit="+limit).then(function(response){
    items = response.data.responseMsg;
    return items;
  });
},
refreshNotice: function(starts, limits){
  return $http.get(BASE_URL+"&start="+starts+"&limit="+limits).then(function(response){
    items = response.data.responseMsg;
    return items;
      });
  }
    }
    })
```

Your HTML part

```
<ion-item class="content double-padding" style="white-space: normal;" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="text-right">{{item.createdAt}}</div>
  <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
  {{item.content}}
</ion-item>

<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore(limit)" distance="5%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

I hope this will help you :-)